# Did Frontinus mention siphons?

Tags: technology

On a rather informative [website on aqueducts](http://www.romanaqueducts.info/siphons/siphons.htm), I came across the following passage:

> **Frontinus** is another classical author who wrote about aqueducts. Around 100 AD he was supervising the aqueducts of Rome and wrote the book 'de aquae ductu'. Remarkably **he did not make any reference to siphons** although in his time they were already applied all over the Greek and Roman world and even in and around Rome.

This is remarkable indeed. Is it true? I wouldn't even know any word for "siphon"; *vectis* seems rather broad?

Comment: *sipho /sipo -onis* (long sip-) amongst others Livy describing some sort of hydraulic phenomenon, leading to a *fons.*

Comment: @Hugh: Hah! That makes sense, I presume it's Greek.

Comment: My Greek lexicon doesn't show if it had the same range of medical, hydraulic, garden-feature meanings as the Latin.

Comment: @Hugh: Yeah, I'll leave that to future respondentes...